# Excluding function in import - namespace

Tags: r, namespaces

My problem is that in my imports there are two packages having the function called `alpha` but in my code I use only that from package `ggplot2` (the other package is `psychometric`). After checking I got this warning:

> Warning: replacing previous import by 'psychometric::alpha' when loading 'mypackage'

Description file:

```
Imports: deltaPlotR, difNLR, difR, foreign, ggplot2, gridExtra, ltm, moments, nnet, psychometric, reshape2, shiny, shinyAce
```

Namespace file:

```
import(shiny,
       shinyAce,
       moments,
       foreign,
       nnet,
       ggplot2,
       reshape2,
       ltm,
       psychometric,
       difR,
       deltaPlotR,
       gridExtra,
       difNLR)
```

While I use a lot of functions from both packages (`ggplot2` and `psychometric`)
I tried to use `import(psychometric, exclude = alpha)` but I got an error:

> ERROR
>   Namespace dependency not required: 'alpha'

Comment: We could call the function with its *full name* : `ggplot2::alpha()`

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks, this is what I need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing namespaces and imports, we can call the function explicitly:

```
ggplot2::alpha()
```